# Is it possible to search my own posts?

Tags: support, search

There is a question about a wireless issue - and I've replied on a post about wireless issue where another user has possibly already given an answer (although it's not a dupe).

So, I wanted to search by thread's I've posted on for the term "wireless". I don't think this can be done.

I assume I'm in the minority wanting this, or does anyone think this is a good idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type [`user:me`](https://superuser.com/search?q=user:me%20wireless) in the search box & you'll be able to search your posts. You can further refine it by adding `is:question` to filter only your questions or `is:answer` to filter out only answers.

Check the search tips for [more such options](https://superuser.com/search).

Comment: Ha, simple question, simple answer :). Thank you once again Sathya.

Comment: @Dave you're welcome :-) have edited to add more details